# Intl.NumberFormat doesn't convert to pt-BR locale

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this sample of code:

```
const formCurrency = new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'BRL',
    minimumFractionDigits: 2
})
```

if the input is:

```
var money = 1000.50

formCurrency.format(money)
```

the expected output is: `R$ 1.000,50`,
but instead it gives: `R$ 1,000.50`

Does anyone know how to change the `,` with `.`, or other way to do this using `Intl`?

I've already tried changing the locale to de-DE, but doesn't work as well. With other `style` the `R$` changes, but the rest of the punctuation don't.

Comment: Node.js doesn't probably bundle the complete ICU database. I presume you'll have to find it elsewhere - https://nodejs.org/api/intl.html

Comment: Thanks for the docs @ÁlvaroGonzález, found a way to do this. I will post the way I used to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Alvaro, I've found a way. According to MDN and Node documentation itself, `Node.js` support only en-US locale. So to make it work I needed to:

- install the `full-icu` package with `npm i full-icu`
- do a `npm-rebuild` after the instalation
- add inside the `package.json` file, add the code:

  `"scripts": { "start":"node --icu-data-dir=node_modules\\full-icu YOURAPP.js" }`
- run the node application with `npm start`

Now it gets the correct locale and do the correct punctuation too.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is a very not optimal solution, but should do the trick

```
let result = formCurrency.format(money);
result = result.split('.');
result[0] = result[0].replace(',' , '.');
result = result.join(',');
```

I tried to do it with regex but couldn't find a good way.

Answer (score 1):

I use the locale 'id'(Indonesia) and it works for me.

```
var number = '1555666.99';
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('id').format(number))
```

```
result: 1.555.666,99
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Steps to take in production (similar to @Mael's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60041299/2873538), but with little changes)

1- Add dependency in package.json (running `npm i full-icu` locally do this before the commit);

2- Add path to `icu-data-dir` before node run your app, then edit your `start` script:

```
"start": "node --icu-data-dir=./node_modules/full-icu yourEntryFile.js"
```

Only these steps did the trick for me. Can be helpful to someone else.

Answer (score -1):

Use this...

```
function convertMoneyValue(number,element){
    number = parseFloat((number/100)).toFixed(2);
    element.value = (new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' }).format(number));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I made a test and works like the example below:

```
const options = { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL', minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 3 }
const formatNumber = new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', options)
     
let number = 9123456.7115544;
console.log(formatNumber.format(number));
// → R$ 9.123.456,712
```

I've tested too on a project in pt-BR, i've created a filter on a project in vue:

```
formatValue(val) {  
    const options = {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "BRL",
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    maximumFractionDigits: 3
  };
  const formatNumber = new Intl.NumberFormat("pt-BR", options);
  return formatNumber.format(val);
  // val: -70549.82999999999
  // formatNumber.format(val): -R$ 70.549,83
},
```

Comment: Ok, i've edited ;)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32979980)

Comment: The answear you proposed is exactly the problem I was having because the pt-BR package was invalid.

Comment: Link reference: https://criarprogramas.com/2021/06/05/formatando-numeros-em-javascript-com-intl-numberformat/

Comment: Strange, works for me =/

Comment: Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oxymus/vc1720zg/7/